# How to preserve timezone when using Time.to_s(:db)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to convert Time object with PST timezone.

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
now = Time.now.in_time_zone(zone)
```

when I output **now**, it's correct. when I do **Time.now.in_time_zone(zone).to_s(:db)**, it outputs GMT (original date).

How do I fix it?

Update: Looks like..the following code works

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
now = Time.now.in_time_zone(zone).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database dates are usually stored in utc time format..

ActiveSupport is returning UTC, not GMT on to_s(:db), 
see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s

EDIT: Maybe this helps you?
http://chris.finne.us/2011/09/23/rails-3-tosdb-when-database-time-is-not-utc/

Comment: Hi Lichtmberg // Thank you for the input and link. I actually found an aswer. Updated.

Comment: Unlike the code above, this will convert the time to UTC. For example: if the local time is "Fri, 08 Apr 2016 19:51:39 EDT -04:00" (Eastern Time, US/Canada),  time.to_s(:db) is "2016-04-08 23:49:02", while time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") is "2016-04-08 19:51:39".